# Is there any function that creates an array from 1 to n, repeating each value m times?

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to implement `SparseArray`, using the function `With` to give the condition for different matrix elements. I would need a function `f`, that instead of doing what `Mod` does,

```
Mod[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, 1]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}

I would like to have:

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, 1]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}

So that,

```
f[1,3,1]
```

> 1

and

```
f[4,3,1]
```

> 2

Does such a function `f` exist?

Comment: Quotient does the job!

Comment: Since everybody's going nuts with alternative solutions: one could also use `Fold[]`+`Riffle[]` for the task...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
Quotient[Range[6], 3, 1] + 1
   {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
```

Comment: Precisely, thanks @J.M you are genius, holly smokes!!:)

Comment: how do you give format to the question?

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for stuff on formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on partial81's answer:

```
reps[n_, m_] := Flatten[ConstantArray[#, m] & /@ Range[n]]
```

This creates an array from 1 to $n$, repeating each value $m$ times. For example:

```
reps[5,3]
{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

```
q = Range[6];
m = 3;
Round[(q + 1)/m]

{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
```

Here's the same kind of idea made into a function (it's a little simpler to use `Ceiling` than `Round`: make $m$ copies of each number from 1 to $n$

```
 reps2[n_, m_] := Ceiling[Range[n m]/m]

 reps2[3,4]
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
arrayFunc[n_, m_] := Flatten[Table[ConstantArray[i, m], {i, 1, n}]]
```

E.g. `arrayFunc[5, 2]` gives `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5}`.

But I admit that I am confused by our definition of your `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more ways, using `Table` and `Array`.

In each case,

`r`: the number of repeats
`n`: the range from 1 to n

```
f[r_,n_]:=Table[i,{i,r},{n}]//Flatten
f[5, 3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5}

```
g[r_,n_]:=Array[#&,{r,n}]//Flatten
g[5, 3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5}

Answer (score 1):

Yet more ways:

```
With[{n = 10, m = 3}, Flatten@Transpose@ConstantArray[Range[n], m]]
```

Or for those who prefer *inefficiency*:

```
With[{n = 10, m = 3}, Flatten@Cases[Range[n], x_ :> ConstantArray[x, m]]]
```